# Что попадает в значение open_files

Tags: mysql

Что в `mysql 5.6 engibe innodb`, попадает в значение `show global status like 'open_files'` кроме файлов таблиц и индексов? Судя по документации там не учитываются `sockets` и `pipes`. А что учитывается и как этот список посмотреть?